# Multiple mongoose call with async

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose

i'm new with **node** and **mongoose**.
I do multiple queries to find my datas so I use **async** to populate an array and then send it back the the client.

I try to get all the stats from the games I found.

Here is my Schema : [Team] 1 ---> N [Game] 1 ---> N [Stat]

```
var json = []; // The variable I will send back

async.waterfall([
  function( team, next ) { // Find all games from a team (with its id)
    dbGame.find({ team_id: req.params._id }).exec( next );
  },
  function( games, next ) {
    for (key in games) {   // For all games, finds their stats 
      dbStat.find({ game_id: games[key]._id }).exec(function(err, stats) {
        json.push({
          _id       : games[key]._id,
          stats     : stats
        }); // The json I need to return
      });
      if ( Number(key) === Number(games.length -1) ) {
        next(json);
      }
    }
  }
], function () {
  res.status(200);
  res.json(json);
});
```

The variable **json** send is always empty because of the asynchronous and I don't know how to have the full one.

---

**update #1**

Ok it's cool it's working.

But just a trouble, all the stats are in all json in the object :

Juste a problem : The stats from all games are stored in all json.

```
[{
 _id:"57cb15f73945ac9808fe5422",
 stats:Array[13]
}, {
 _id:"57ff76fd78ca91a17b25dd1b",
 stats :Array[13]
}]
```

But I think i can sort then. Here's my code now :

```
async.waterfall([
  function(next) { // Find all games from a team (with its id)
    dbGame.find({
      team_id: req.params._id
    }).sort({
      _id: 1
    }).exec(next);
  },
  function(games, next) {
    var gameIds = games.map(function(game) {
      return game._id;
    });
    dbStat.find({
      game_id: {
        $in: gameIds
      }
    }).sort({game_id: 1}).exec(function(err, stats) {
      json = gameIds.map(function (id) {
        return {
          _id: id,
            stats: stats
          }
        });
        next(err, json);
    });
  }
], function(err, json) {
  jsonResponse(res, 200, json);
});
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are not [passing the results of the first find to the next step of waterfall](http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#waterfall), and when you call `next(json);` you are passing json as error, as the first argument is an error. Try:

```
async.waterfall([
    function(team, next) { // Find all games from a team (with its id)
        dbGame.find({
            team_id: req.params._id
        }).sort({
            _id: 1
        }).exec(next(err, games));
    },
    function(games, next) {
        var gameIds = games.map(function(game) {
            return game._id;
        });

        dbStat.find({
            game_id: {
                $in: gameIds
            }
        }).sort({game_id: 1}).exec(function(err, stats) {
          json = gameIds.map(function (id) {
            return {
              _id: id,
              stats: stats
            }
          });
          next(err, json);
        });
    }
], function(err, json) {
    res.status(200);
    res.json(json);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
var json = []; // The variable I will send back

async.waterfall([
    function(team, next) { // Find all games from a team (with its id)
        dbGame.find({
            team_id: req.params._id
        }).sort({
            _id: 1
        }).exec(next);
    },
    function(games, next) {
        var gameIds = games.map(function(game) {
            return game._id;
        });

        dbStat.find({
            game_id: {
                $in: gameIds
            }
        }).sort({game_id: 1}).exec(function(err, stats) {
          json = gameIds.map(function (id) {
            return {
              _id: id,
              stats: stats
            }
          });
          next(err, json);
        });
    }
], function() {
    res.status(200);
    res.json(json);
});
```

Comment if it has any issue or I have missed something as I have not tested it.